# A conjecture on products/composition of Pell forms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Based on a few brute-force calculations, I've formulated the following.

**Conjecture.** Let $x,y,u,v,p,q,a,b,c \ge 2$ be integers such that
$$
(x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2) = p^2+cq^2,
$$
and write
\begin{align}
 g_1 &= \gcd(x,y)\gcd(u,v)\gcd(p,q),  \\
 g_2 &= \gcd(a,xy)\gcd(b,uv)\gcd(c,pq),  \\
 g_3 &= \gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)\gcd(b,c).
\end{align}
Then $g_1g_2g_3>1$.

Is the conjecture true? What would be a good way of trying to prove it? Alternatively, what would be a good way of narrowing the search for counterexamples (*e.g.*, modular considerations, *etc.*)?

Note that it isn't enough to simply restrict $g_1 = 1$, since
$$(x,a,y,u,b,v,p,c,q)=(2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 10, 9)$$
is a solution with $g_1=1$ (but $g_2g_3>1$).

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have an equation of the form
$$
(x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2) = p^2+cq^2,
$$
where $a,b,c$ are pairwise relatively prime squarefree integers.

Are there any important results regarding this special equation?

EDIT: In *Composition of Binary Forms and the Foundation of Mathematics*, Harold M. Edwards says that Gauss [ca. Art 235/236 of *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*] proved the following theorem:

**If $f$ and $\phi$ can be composed, the ratio of their determinants must be a ratio of squares.**

Is this really a necessary and sufficient condition? If so, doesn’t the fact that my equation
$$
  (x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2) = p^2+cq^2
$$
have two forms on the left-hand side being composed into the single form on the right-hand side then demand that the determinants of the two left-hand forms must be a ratio of squares?

EDIT: Cross-posted to MO [a more specific question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181242/does-the-diophantine-equation-x2ay2u2bv2-p2cq2-admit-a-complete) about the existence or derivation of a complete solution.

Comment: Is your meaning that one considers $a,b,c$ as given fixed pairwise coprime, and then trys to show existence or construction of choices for $x,y,u,v,p,q$? [Or maybe are you doing the reverse, and simply asking how to find triples $a,b,c$ for which there are values of the other variables to make the relation hold?]

Comment: Your conditions preclude the one thing that resembles this, Arndt gave a recipe, pages 129-131 in Buell.

Comment: $(x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2)=(tp)^2+c(tq)^2=t^2(p^2+cq^2)$ The solution of the equation: $x^2+ay^2=t^2$ It turns. $x=p^2-as^2$ ; $y=2ps$ ; $t=p^2+as^2$ For the equation: $u^2+bv^2=p^2+cq^2$ There are solutions if the number of $(bc)$ or $(b-c+1)$ square.

Comment: @coffeemath: The former. I have $a,b,c$, and the others are to be constructed. Almost-best-case scenario: $x,y,u,v,p,q$ are polynomials in $a,b,c$. Best-case scenario: it's "if and only if".

Comment: @WillJagy: Are you referring to _Algorithmic Number Theory_, or something else?

Comment: @WillJagy: More likely, this: <http://books.google.ca/books/about/Binary_Quadratic_Forms.html?id=qMa8-FDOR8YC>, yes?

Comment: @WillJagy: Are you saying it's impossible with that restriction, or just that with the restriction we can't use Arndt's recipe?

Comment: @individ: In that case, are there solutions __if and only if__ $bc$ or $b-c+1$ is a square?

Comment: In General, the formula looks like this:  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98937 should the corresponding coefficients to deliver. Given the equivalent quadratic form.

Comment: @individ: The images on the linked site appear to be broken.

Comment: Then the formula can't draw. Removed.

Comment: Got your email. The behavior with $a,b,c$ constants has essentially no bearing on the case when $a,b,c$ depend on the other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind: I found a counterexample…

$$(x,a,y,u,b,v,p,c,q)=(1471528, 9777203, 9668027, 5703851, 3364185, 2582134, 16, 819951918602068063799187294877418918951, 5)$$

Comment: The formula in the General form for this equation is very long. What's the point of wasting time and to write it?

Comment: If you have a general formula for ALL solutions, it could be used to prove some very powerful theorems very simply. That's the point.

Comment: Is your general formula somehow derived from my counterexample? If so, I'm sure we can find a much smaller counterexample as a "seed value".

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt to show that
$$(x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2)=p^2+cq^2 \tag{1}$$ 
has solutions, without conditions on $a,b,c$ beyond their being distinct. We first select $x,y$ to make $x^2+ay^2=m^2.$ If $a=1$ we may use any pythagorean triple, say $(x,y)=(3,4)$ and $m=5.$ Otherwise put $x=a-1,\ y=2,\ m=a+1$ since $(a-1)^2+4a=(a+1)^2.$ [Note: since later we divide by $m^2$ we need $m \neq 0$ so if by chance $a=-1$ we may use $x=5,\ y=4,\ m=3.$] Replacing the first factor of $(1)$ by $m^2$ and multiply through, we have
$$(mu)^2+b(mv)^2=p^2+cq^2.$$
In this, put $q=mv,\ p=ms$ (where $s$ is a "new" variable to be determined) and divide by $m^2$ to obtain
$$u^2+bv^2=s^2+cv^2.\tag{2}$$
At this point the argument branches on whether $|c-b|$ is a square. First assume it is not. Then there are the two rearrangements
$$u^2-(c-b)v^2=s^2,\\ s^2-(b-c)v^2=u^2.\tag{3}$$
Depending on the sign of $c-b$ the left side of one of these is that of a Pell equation $m^2-Dn^2=1$ [with $D>0$ and $D$ not a square], and we may take our right side $s^2$ or $u^2$ to be $1$ to make one of these exactly a Pell equation (with the $1$ on the right). Since the Pell equation has solutions we have a solution to $(1).$

The remaining case, wherein $|c-b|$ is a square, say $k^2,$ is simple; take a 3-4-5 pythagorean triple and multiply it through by $k^2$ depending on which one of $(3)$ is chosen.

Note that, as pointed out by @individ, one really does not need Pell to solve equation $(2).$

Comment: Above given formula for the equation; $u^2+bv^2=s^2+cv^2$ always gives a solution. And the Pell equation is not necessary.

Comment: @coffeemath: Thanks! I'm trying to put together a "complete solution", and this will definitely help.

Comment: @individ: Your formula is also helpful, but it assumes $p,q$ have a common factor, and that the first factor is a square. This is a good special case to have in my "complete solution".

Comment: @individ How does one (specifically) get a solution to (2) of above answer without use of Pell? [just curious...]

Comment: @KierenMacMillan By "put together a complete solution" do you mean your goal is to find *all* values of $x,y,u,v,p,q$ for each specific choice of fixed $a,b,c$? If so that looks a lot more difficult than just showing existence of *some* values of these other parameters. And in another comment you seem to say it's a drawback that p,q have a common factor, so one wonders just what are the goals for x,y,u,v,p,q in the solution?

Comment: @coffeemath: When I attack a Diophantine equation, I _always_ start by hoping I can find a "complete solution", which is an integer parameterization if it admits one, or a characterization of all possible cases otherwise.

Sometimes, this task is relatively easy (_e.g._, equal sums of squares); in other cases it is more difficult; in many (most?) cases, I have to give up fighting that particular windmill.

I didn't mean to say that $\gcd(p,q)>1$ is a _drawback_: it’s a [useful] restriction. If I could prove that $\gcd(p,q)>1$ is a __necessary condition__, that would be great.

Comment: @coffeemath: For the record, I upvoted your answer — it's very helpful. I'm going to try to expand on your solution for $x^2+ay^2=Mm^2$ and $u^2+bv^2=Nn^2$ with $M,N$ squarefree, which would of course be a "complete solution" (_i.e._ it would admit all possible values of the factors on the left-hand side).

Comment: It's just. The formula holds when $u^2+(b-c)v^2=s^2$ When $(b-c)$ is greater than zero. If less redraw slightly different form.

Comment: @individ I agree no Pell needed, as one can do a rational parametrization of $u^2+(b-v)v^2=1$ based on the initial solution $u=1,v=0$ and then multiplying through by a denominator. I'll throw that in, citing your input.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to say a few words about the formula about which I have spoken. For the equation: $$(x^2+ay^2)(u^2+bv^2)=p^2+cq^2$$

Need to write this simple formula.

$$x=r^2-as^2$$

$$y=2rs$$

$$u=(k^2-bt^2)(n^2+cj^2)$$

$$v=2kt(n^2+cj^2)$$

$$p=(r^2+as^2)(k^2+bt^2)(n^2-cj^2)$$

$$q=(r^2+as^2)(k^2+bt^2)2nj$$

I think that this formula gives all solutions. Mutually simple solution obtained after reduction to common divisor.

For example there was a similar situation with the equation: $X^2+Y^2=Z^{n}$

It is enough to write the formula generates an endless series of decisions in all degrees.  For this we use the Pythagorean triple.   And the number of their sets.

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$   $$a=2ps$$   $$b=p^2-s^2$$   $$c=p^2+s^2$$

$p,s$ - what some integers.   Then the solution can be written.
$$X=2psc^{n-1}$$   $$Y=(p^2-s^2)c^{n-1}$$   $$Z=c^2$$

And mutually simple solutions can get if you cut down on common divisor. Although there will be not one simple solution.

Comment: As a set of formulas, this is rather amazing. I will need to prove whether it is the __complete__ solution, before I can wield it like the Odinsword… but thank you for even putting me on the right path.

Comment: This can't be the complete solution: considering my counterexample (see other answer), we have $\gcd(u,v)=1$. Hence $n^2+cj^2=1$, and since $c>1$, we must have $j=0$ and $n=\pm1$. But now $q=0$, which is not true of my counterexample.

Comment: I realise you may have meant that the complete solution with no common factors would be:
\begin{align}
x &= r^2-as^2  \\
y & = 2rs  \\
u &= k^2-bt^2  \\
v &= 2kt  \\
p &= n^2-cj^2  \\
q &= 2nj,
\end{align}
where all of the common __polynomial__ factors have been removed. But this also can't be the complete solution, since my counterexample has $y$ odd, and your solution forces $y$ to be even.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan I meant that after substitution of different factors. Then reduce by common divisor. In this case, will mutually simple solutions?